# C#.net docusign Api call return error ( The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive)

Tags: docusignapi

For the DocuSign Signature Appliance:

C#.net `Docusign` Api call returned an error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive
```

`Docusign` URL contain two part (`baseURL`, `ResourcePath`).
sending document for sign as base64string.see the following code.

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{           
    String baseURL = "https://prime-dsa-devctr.docusign.net:8081";
    String resourcePath = "sapiws/v1/digital_signature";
    String apiUrl = baseURL + "/" + resourcePath;
    var client = new RestClient(apiUrl);            
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.PUT);
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic " + DSABasicAuthorizationString("xxxx@xxx.com", "####"));
    // "digital_signature" request body as Json formated String (use JavaScriptSerializer or Newtonsoft.Json to build from object) 
    String DigSigRequestBody =
        "{ \"CreateAndSignField\" : " + //structure name specifies the operation / function
            "{   \"file\": " + "\"" + File2Base64String("C:\\work\\PurchaseOrder.pdf") + "\", " +
                "\"fileType\": \"PDF\", " +
                "\"x\": \"91\", " +
                "\"y\": \"164\", " +
                "\"width\": \"113\", " +
                "\"height\": \"38\", " +
                "\"page\": \"1\", " +
                "\"timeFormat\": \"h:mm:ss\", " +
                "\"dateFormat\": \"dd/MM/yyyy\", " +
                "\"appearance\": [\"GRAPHICAL_IMAGE\", \"SIGNED_BY\", \"TIME\"]" +
            "}" +
        "}";
    request.AddParameter("application/json", DigSigRequestBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);            
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);            
    JObject joResponse = JObject.Parse(response.Content);

    Base64String2Path(joResponse["signedFile"].Value<string>(), "C:\\work\\PurchaseOrder.DSA-REST-SIGNED.pdf");
    Console.WriteLine("success");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void Base64String2Path(string Base64String, string FilePath)
{
    Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64String);
    File.WriteAllBytes(FilePath, bytes);
}

private static String File2Base64String(String FilePath)
{
    Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
    String fileB64Data = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    return fileB64Data;
}

private static String DSABasicAuthorizationString(String username, string password)
{
    var DSABasicAuthorizationBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(DSABasicAuthorizationBytes);
}
```

Comment: Did it ever work? (Was this a transient error?)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the service is currently down for maintenance, please contact our DSA support (DSASupport@DocuSign.com) and they will provide additional options.

Answer (score 0):

That DocuSign Signature Appliance trial system is currently offline awaiting a software update from DocuSign Engineering.

For more information, ask your DocuSign technical contact or salesperson for status. Reference DocuSign ticket CSNC-1521